# How to implement a List(of Task) functions as a queue? (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

As simple as I can:

- Multi-thread WPF Window app.
- All threads query single device via ssh.
- Device can have multiple same-users, but IO stack won't let app (obviously).

Trying to ask a 'legal' way:

How can I create a Queue (FIFO) of tasks/actions that each return a string from their function?

2014-06-21 UPDATE

This is where I am now. I can create the Tasks on the ConcurrentQueue.

The issue remains as to how to modify this to allow a task to be created/called, the task put into the FIFO queue, and that tasks's result (String) be returned to the variable that called it, like:

*Dim result = Task...("the command")...*

The below is my foundation for testing ways to do this (compiles & runs):

```
Dim TCQ As New ConcurrentQueue(Of Task)
Sub Main()
        ' This simulates program calls to Enqueue tasks on TCQ:
        For i = 1 To 20
            TCQ.Enqueue(GetTask(Date.Now.ToLongTimeString & " - Command number " & i))
        Next
        ' normally, TCQ would be watched in a loop
        Do While TCQ.Count > 0
            Dim tsk As Task = Nothing
            TCQ.TryDequeue(tsk)
            tsk.Wait()
            Console.WriteLine(Date.Now.ToLongTimeString & " [" & tsk.Id & "] post-Wait(): " & tsk.Id & " TCQ.Count: " & TCQ.Count)
        Loop
        Console.WriteLine("done.")
        Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

This next function creates a task with the command string in it...

```
Function GetTask(CommandString As String) As Task(Of String)
        Dim t As Task(Of String) = Nothing
        Dim cts As New CancellationTokenSource()
        Dim ct As CancellationToken = cts.Token
        Try
            t = Task(Of String).Factory.StartNew(Function()
                                                     Return GetCommandResults(CommandString, ct)
                                                 End Function, ct, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning)
            t.Wait()
            Console.WriteLine("GetTask.Id: " & t.Id & " result: " & t.Result)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("Caught Exception: " & ex.ToString)
        End Try
        Return t
End Function
```

This function is for sending the command to the device, and storing the response as a string as well...

```
Function GetCommandResults(theCommand As String, ct As CancellationToken) As String
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("--> starting  GetCommandResults({0})", theCommand))
        Thread.Sleep(2000)
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("<-- done with GetCommandResults({0})", theCommand))
        Return String.Format(Date.Now.ToLongTimeString & " - GetCommandResults returned {0}", theCommand)
End Function
```

And yields:

```
[Main()] before creating tasks
--> starting  GetCommandResults(8:14:38 PM - Command number 1)
<-- done with GetCommandResults(8:14:38 PM - Command number 1)
GetTask.Id: 1 result: 8:14:40 PM - GetCommandResults returned 8:14:38 PM - Command number 1
--> starting  GetCommandResults(8:14:40 PM - Command number 2)
<-- done with GetCommandResults(8:14:40 PM - Command number 2)
GetTask.Id: 2 result: 8:14:42 PM - GetCommandResults returned 8:14:40 PM - Command number 2
--> starting  GetCommandResults(8:14:42 PM - Command number 3)
<-- done with GetCommandResults(8:14:42 PM - Command number 3)
GetTask.Id: 3 result: 8:14:44 PM - GetCommandResults returned 8:14:42 PM - Command number 3
[...]
```

So if I had to write it out logically:

1. A String variable is prepared as the output of a created task, using a command string.
2. The String command is put into the ConcurrentQueue.
3. When the Task is Dequeued from the ConcurrentQueue, it is run, and the result of the command returned to the calling variable.

So, you could say I'm looking for a way to do this, but as described above with a synchronous queue:

Dim result as String = Await Task.Factory.StartNew(Function()
                                                       Dim r as String = FunctionThatReturnsString()
                                                       Return r
                                                   End Function)

...except I can't seem to stop the Tasks from executing as soon as they are created...

Hope this update helps!

Comment: I'm just trying to get command requests for a router from various tasks, and ensure only one at a time is executing them & getting the response (all as strings)... :)

Comment: Interesting that such a horrible question/post, with negative 'clicks' gets so many views...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No better way to do this than to propose as a solution. Since there hasn't been any action on it (no points for a tough question, even), I hope the moderators will look the other way as I ask how this could be made better-*but without question marks!*

To sum this solution attempt up:

1. The caller either creates or uses the singleton JobQSingleton().
2. The caller uses the q by creating a unique guid (for looking up results later), and the job as a string:

   Dim jobId As Guid = Guid.NewGuid
   Dim myCommand As String = "Command for Job #" & i
3. The caller creates a Job() instance, loads it with the above params, and submits it to the q:

   Dim j as Job = New Job()
   j.CallerJobID = jobId
   j.Command = myCommand
   j.CallerName = "caller #" & i
   TheJobQ.JobRequest(j)
4. Lastly, the caller waits on the result by calling GetJobResultAsync() on TheJobQ, using the guid it supplied with the job when submitted as the 'index', if you will, to locate the results:

   Dim jobResult As String = TheJobQ.GetJobResultAsync(CallerJobID).Result

The working example is here, but it leaves many questions in my mind, a big one being whether putting Tasks on the queue qould be better, a la:

```
Dim t As New Task(AddressOf Me.TakeFromQLoop, ct, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning)
...add to queue; when time, pull off queue and...
t.Start()
```

For discussion: I cannot find a way to keep the tasks attached to their callers as they pass into/out of the q. Doing so might be a lot less convoluted. This was hinted at in the OP.

---

Luckily, I wrote this test/use case in one module for easy copy/pasting. It works as is in VS2012:

```
Imports System.Collections.Concurrent

Module Module1
    Dim TheJobQ As JobQSingleton
    '
    Sub Main()
        TheJobQ = JobQSingleton.GetInstance ' only 1 class can do work (serially/synchronously)
        '
        ' step 1: create the jobs
        '
        Dim jobList As New ConcurrentQueue(Of Job)      ' each client comes up with their own Guid to later retriece their job's results
        Dim jobIdList As New ConcurrentQueue(Of Guid)   ' this list holds those Guid, so we can iterate at the end and get the results
        For i = 1 To 10
            Dim jobId As Guid = Guid.NewGuid
            Dim myCommand As String = "Command for Job #" & i
            Console.WriteLine("[{0}] CallerJobID: {1} Command: {2}", i, jobId.ToString, myCommand)
            jobList.Enqueue(New Job() With {.CallerJobID = jobId, .Command = myCommand, .CallerName = "caller #" & i})
            jobIdList.Enqueue(jobId)
        Next
        '
        ' step 2: submit requests
        '
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
        For Each jReq As Job In jobList
            If jobList.TryDequeue(jReq) Then
                TheJobQ.JobRequest(jReq)
            End If
            Console.WriteLine("[{2}] {0} added {1} to the Q via .JobRequest", jReq.CallerName, jReq.CallerJobID, jobList.Count)
        Next
        '
        ' step 3: get results (using retrieveQ created earlier from copying jobList)
        '
        For Each clientJobId As Guid In jobIdList '.Reverse ' simulates all our clients' provided Guids
            Dim jobResult As String = GetWorkResult(clientJobId)
            Console.WriteLine("Result of client jobId: {0} is: ""{1}""", clientJobId, jobResult, jobIdList.Count)
        Next
        Console.WriteLine("done.")
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
    '
    ' step 3a: 
    '
    Public Function GetWorkResult(CallerJobID As Guid) As String
        Dim r As String = ""
        r = TheJobQ.GetJobResultAsync(CallerJobID).Result
        Return r
    End Function
    '
    '========================================================================
    '
    ' JobQ()
    '
    Public Class JobQSingleton
#Region "class vars"
        ' singleton instance
        Shared myInstance As JobQSingleton
        ' requests
        Private Q As New ConcurrentQueue(Of Job)
        ' results
        Private ResultsDictionary As New ConcurrentDictionary(Of Guid, Job)
        Private DoQLoop As Boolean
#End Region
#Region "constructor"
        Private Sub New()
            Me.DoQLoop = True
            Me.StartLoop()
        End Sub
        Public Shared Function GetInstance() As JobQSingleton
            If IsNothing(myInstance) Then
                myInstance = New JobQSingleton
            End If
            Return myInstance
        End Function
        Private Sub StartLoop()
            Dim cts As New Threading.CancellationTokenSource
            Dim ct As Threading.CancellationToken = cts.Token
            ' (a) with .Start():
            'Dim t As New Task(AddressOf Me.TakeFromQLoop, ct, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning)
            't.Start()
            ' (b) simple AddressOf:
            Dim t As Task = task.Factory.StartNew(AddressOf Me.TakeFromQLoop, ct, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning)
            '
            Console.WriteLine("Loop started")
        End Sub
#End Region
#Region "(public) submit/retrieve jobs"
        '=======================================================
        '
        ' step 2a: add a guid for internal use/deugging
        '
        Public Sub JobRequest(aJobRequest As Job)
            With aJobRequest
                .QJobID = Guid.NewGuid  ' our internal ID
            End With
            Me.AddJob(aJobRequest)
        End Sub
        Public Async Function GetJobResultAsync(ByVal jobId As Guid) As Task(Of String)
            Return Await Task.Run(Of String)(Function() GetJobResult(jobId))
        End Function
        '
        ' callers call one of the above 2 to either give a job, or get results
        '
        '=======================================================
        Private Function GetJobResult(jobId As Guid) As String
            Do Until Me.ResultsDictionary.ContainsKey(jobId)
                Threading.Thread.Sleep(250)
            Loop
            Return Me.ResultsDictionary.Item(jobId).Response
        End Function
#End Region
        Private Sub AddJob(j As Job)
            Q.Enqueue(j)
        End Sub
        Private Sub TakeFromQLoop()
            While (Me.DoQLoop)
                Dim j As New Job
                If Q.TryPeek(j) = True Then
                    If Q.TryDequeue(j) = True Then
                        With j
                            Console.WriteLine("===> Start job ID {0} from caller {1}", .CallerJobID, .CallerName)
                            Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
                            j.Response = String.Format("The result of the command {0} is {1}", j.Command, Date.Now.ToLongTimeString)
                            If Me.ResultsDictionary.TryAdd(j.CallerJobID, j) Then
                                Console.WriteLine("<===  Stop job ID {0} from caller {1}", .CallerJobID, .CallerName)
                            Else
                                Console.WriteLine("...error...")
                            End If
                        End With
                    End If
                End If
                Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
            End While
        End Sub
    End Class
    '
    ' holds the job & results...
    '
    Public Class Job
        Public Property JobName As String
        Public Property QJobID As Guid
        Public Property CallerName As String
        Public Property CallerJobID As Guid
        Public Property Command As String
        Public Property Response As String
    End Class
End Module
```

Output (*not* using the .Reverse option commented out above)

```
Loop started
[1] CallerJobID: d4a1f479-1d27-4b2f-8d9c-5db1fbacf906 Command: Command for Job #1
[2] CallerJobID: 06a4a886-4054-426b-b963-88e54d4aeda7 Command: Command for Job #2
[3] CallerJobID: 1415bb08-607c-4bf0-9b28-a1f33eb24c33 Command: Command for Job #3
[4] CallerJobID: 18568325-ce4e-4ece-aeff-4f03b20567bf Command: Command for Job #4
[5] CallerJobID: adaffd34-8c76-48eb-a9e3-dbbf3d7cfd1f Command: Command for Job #5
[6] CallerJobID: fabc4ae2-681c-44fa-be83-24c185fc6a54 Command: Command for Job #6
[7] CallerJobID: 7532a8f8-8f97-471a-914b-e1dd9cc88f29 Command: Command for Job #7
[8] CallerJobID: 433338db-94d3-41c1-a003-f883a57059ca Command: Command for Job #8
[9] CallerJobID: b1a47e95-c48c-4b36-b6eb-1c582148d564 Command: Command for Job #9
[10] CallerJobID: 63707629-2140-431b-a91f-13f0b8a37239 Command: Command for Job #10
[9] caller #1 added d4a1f479-1d27-4b2f-8d9c-5db1fbacf906 to the Q via .JobRequest
[8] caller #2 added 06a4a886-4054-426b-b963-88e54d4aeda7 to the Q via .JobRequest
[7] caller #3 added 1415bb08-607c-4bf0-9b28-a1f33eb24c33 to the Q via .JobRequest
[6] caller #4 added 18568325-ce4e-4ece-aeff-4f03b20567bf to the Q via .JobRequest
[5] caller #5 added adaffd34-8c76-48eb-a9e3-dbbf3d7cfd1f to the Q via .JobRequest
[4] caller #6 added fabc4ae2-681c-44fa-be83-24c185fc6a54 to the Q via .JobRequest
[3] caller #7 added 7532a8f8-8f97-471a-914b-e1dd9cc88f29 to the Q via .JobRequest
[2] caller #8 added 433338db-94d3-41c1-a003-f883a57059ca to the Q via .JobRequest
[1] caller #9 added b1a47e95-c48c-4b36-b6eb-1c582148d564 to the Q via .JobRequest
[0] caller #10 added 63707629-2140-431b-a91f-13f0b8a37239 to the Q via .JobRequest
===> Start job ID d4a1f479-1d27-4b2f-8d9c-5db1fbacf906 from caller caller #1
<===  Stop job ID d4a1f479-1d27-4b2f-8d9c-5db1fbacf906 from caller caller #1
Result of client jobId: d4a1f479-1d27-4b2f-8d9c-5db1fbacf906 is: "The result of the command Command for Job #1 is 7:27:41 PM"
===> Start job ID 06a4a886-4054-426b-b963-88e54d4aeda7 from caller caller #2
<===  Stop job ID 06a4a886-4054-426b-b963-88e54d4aeda7 from caller caller #2
Result of client jobId: 06a4a886-4054-426b-b963-88e54d4aeda7 is: "The result of the command Command for Job #2 is 7:27:43 PM"
===> Start job ID 1415bb08-607c-4bf0-9b28-a1f33eb24c33 from caller caller #3
<===  Stop job ID 1415bb08-607c-4bf0-9b28-a1f33eb24c33 from caller caller #3
Result of client jobId: 1415bb08-607c-4bf0-9b28-a1f33eb24c33 is: "The result of the command Command for Job #3 is 7:27:45 PM"
===> Start job ID 18568325-ce4e-4ece-aeff-4f03b20567bf from caller caller #4
<===  Stop job ID 18568325-ce4e-4ece-aeff-4f03b20567bf from caller caller #4
Result of client jobId: 18568325-ce4e-4ece-aeff-4f03b20567bf is: "The result of the command Command for Job #4 is 7:27:47 PM"
===> Start job ID adaffd34-8c76-48eb-a9e3-dbbf3d7cfd1f from caller caller #5
<===  Stop job ID adaffd34-8c76-48eb-a9e3-dbbf3d7cfd1f from caller caller #5
Result of client jobId: adaffd34-8c76-48eb-a9e3-dbbf3d7cfd1f is: "The result of the command Command for Job #5 is 7:27:49 PM"
===> Start job ID fabc4ae2-681c-44fa-be83-24c185fc6a54 from caller caller #6
<===  Stop job ID fabc4ae2-681c-44fa-be83-24c185fc6a54 from caller caller #6
Result of client jobId: fabc4ae2-681c-44fa-be83-24c185fc6a54 is: "The result of the command Command for Job #6 is 7:27:51 PM"
===> Start job ID 7532a8f8-8f97-471a-914b-e1dd9cc88f29 from caller caller #7
<===  Stop job ID 7532a8f8-8f97-471a-914b-e1dd9cc88f29 from caller caller #7
Result of client jobId: 7532a8f8-8f97-471a-914b-e1dd9cc88f29 is: "The result of the command Command for Job #7 is 7:27:53 PM"
===> Start job ID 433338db-94d3-41c1-a003-f883a57059ca from caller caller #8
<===  Stop job ID 433338db-94d3-41c1-a003-f883a57059ca from caller caller #8
Result of client jobId: 433338db-94d3-41c1-a003-f883a57059ca is: "The result of the command Command for Job #8 is 7:27:55 PM"
===> Start job ID b1a47e95-c48c-4b36-b6eb-1c582148d564 from caller caller #9
<===  Stop job ID b1a47e95-c48c-4b36-b6eb-1c582148d564 from caller caller #9
Result of client jobId: b1a47e95-c48c-4b36-b6eb-1c582148d564 is: "The result of the command Command for Job #9 is 7:27:57 PM"
===> Start job ID 63707629-2140-431b-a91f-13f0b8a37239 from caller caller #10
<===  Stop job ID 63707629-2140-431b-a91f-13f0b8a37239 from caller caller #10
Result of client jobId: 63707629-2140-431b-a91f-13f0b8a37239 is: "The result of the command Command for Job #10 is 7:27:59 PM"
done.
```

...and this time *WITH* the .Reverse uncommented:

```
Loop started
[1] CallerJobID: 596de3ee-04e2-49dd-aaeb-e4a2aa41c90a Command: Command for Job #1
[2] CallerJobID: cbf0ab0d-5637-4708-837b-3bf7d605f6e1 Command: Command for Job #2
[3] CallerJobID: d8ba30c6-7729-4f91-8d86-51dfbf3b4b3f Command: Command for Job #3
[4] CallerJobID: 292d6212-de33-471a-9fdc-dad8b4bef4d4 Command: Command for Job #4
[5] CallerJobID: 992af5e4-a713-400c-9792-578ac39c6879 Command: Command for Job #5
[6] CallerJobID: f87a09fa-8cba-4d56-9658-567f0ef6d63e Command: Command for Job #6
[7] CallerJobID: fc7a1f0c-1a75-44ce-93bf-dc80d6c810c7 Command: Command for Job #7
[8] CallerJobID: 01d6af2c-5998-4b38-9244-006e9e12f309 Command: Command for Job #8
[9] CallerJobID: cae99dd9-e7e2-4614-be5b-a75d944e27bd Command: Command for Job #9
[10] CallerJobID: 3f02a3bb-5667-48fb-ab22-df8d951b2b13 Command: Command for Job #10
[9] caller #1 added 596de3ee-04e2-49dd-aaeb-e4a2aa41c90a to the Q via .JobRequest
[8] caller #2 added cbf0ab0d-5637-4708-837b-3bf7d605f6e1 to the Q via .JobRequest
[7] caller #3 added d8ba30c6-7729-4f91-8d86-51dfbf3b4b3f to the Q via .JobRequest
[6] caller #4 added 292d6212-de33-471a-9fdc-dad8b4bef4d4 to the Q via .JobRequest
[5] caller #5 added 992af5e4-a713-400c-9792-578ac39c6879 to the Q via .JobRequest
[4] caller #6 added f87a09fa-8cba-4d56-9658-567f0ef6d63e to the Q via .JobRequest
[3] caller #7 added fc7a1f0c-1a75-44ce-93bf-dc80d6c810c7 to the Q via .JobRequest
[2] caller #8 added 01d6af2c-5998-4b38-9244-006e9e12f309 to the Q via .JobRequest
[1] caller #9 added cae99dd9-e7e2-4614-be5b-a75d944e27bd to the Q via .JobRequest
[0] caller #10 added 3f02a3bb-5667-48fb-ab22-df8d951b2b13 to the Q via .JobRequest
===> Start job ID 596de3ee-04e2-49dd-aaeb-e4a2aa41c90a from caller caller #1
<===  Stop job ID 596de3ee-04e2-49dd-aaeb-e4a2aa41c90a from caller caller #1
===> Start job ID cbf0ab0d-5637-4708-837b-3bf7d605f6e1 from caller caller #2
<===  Stop job ID cbf0ab0d-5637-4708-837b-3bf7d605f6e1 from caller caller #2
===> Start job ID d8ba30c6-7729-4f91-8d86-51dfbf3b4b3f from caller caller #3
<===  Stop job ID d8ba30c6-7729-4f91-8d86-51dfbf3b4b3f from caller caller #3
===> Start job ID 292d6212-de33-471a-9fdc-dad8b4bef4d4 from caller caller #4
<===  Stop job ID 292d6212-de33-471a-9fdc-dad8b4bef4d4 from caller caller #4
===> Start job ID 992af5e4-a713-400c-9792-578ac39c6879 from caller caller #5
<===  Stop job ID 992af5e4-a713-400c-9792-578ac39c6879 from caller caller #5
===> Start job ID f87a09fa-8cba-4d56-9658-567f0ef6d63e from caller caller #6
<===  Stop job ID f87a09fa-8cba-4d56-9658-567f0ef6d63e from caller caller #6
===> Start job ID fc7a1f0c-1a75-44ce-93bf-dc80d6c810c7 from caller caller #7
<===  Stop job ID fc7a1f0c-1a75-44ce-93bf-dc80d6c810c7 from caller caller #7
===> Start job ID 01d6af2c-5998-4b38-9244-006e9e12f309 from caller caller #8
<===  Stop job ID 01d6af2c-5998-4b38-9244-006e9e12f309 from caller caller #8
===> Start job ID cae99dd9-e7e2-4614-be5b-a75d944e27bd from caller caller #9
<===  Stop job ID cae99dd9-e7e2-4614-be5b-a75d944e27bd from caller caller #9
===> Start job ID 3f02a3bb-5667-48fb-ab22-df8d951b2b13 from caller caller #10
<===  Stop job ID 3f02a3bb-5667-48fb-ab22-df8d951b2b13 from caller caller #10
Result of client jobId: 3f02a3bb-5667-48fb-ab22-df8d951b2b13 is: "The result of the command Command for Job #10 is 7:30:12 PM"
Result of client jobId: cae99dd9-e7e2-4614-be5b-a75d944e27bd is: "The result of the command Command for Job #9 is 7:30:10 PM"
Result of client jobId: 01d6af2c-5998-4b38-9244-006e9e12f309 is: "The result of the command Command for Job #8 is 7:30:08 PM"
Result of client jobId: fc7a1f0c-1a75-44ce-93bf-dc80d6c810c7 is: "The result of the command Command for Job #7 is 7:30:06 PM"
Result of client jobId: f87a09fa-8cba-4d56-9658-567f0ef6d63e is: "The result of the command Command for Job #6 is 7:30:04 PM"
Result of client jobId: 992af5e4-a713-400c-9792-578ac39c6879 is: "The result of the command Command for Job #5 is 7:30:02 PM"
Result of client jobId: 292d6212-de33-471a-9fdc-dad8b4bef4d4 is: "The result of the command Command for Job #4 is 7:30:00 PM"
Result of client jobId: d8ba30c6-7729-4f91-8d86-51dfbf3b4b3f is: "The result of the command Command for Job #3 is 7:29:58 PM"
Result of client jobId: cbf0ab0d-5637-4708-837b-3bf7d605f6e1 is: "The result of the command Command for Job #2 is 7:29:56 PM"
Result of client jobId: 596de3ee-04e2-49dd-aaeb-e4a2aa41c90a is: "The result of the command Command for Job #1 is 7:29:54 PM"
done.
```

P.S. Yes, I did use the terms 'job' and 'work' and 'request' synonymously... It was/is a Frankenstein...
P.S.S. I did not include deleting Dictionary entries that contain solutions once they were 'picked up'... Not until I get peer feedback will I tidy things up...

I'm not allowed to end a solution post with a question mark, so you will have to imagine that it is there...

Comment: Since nobody has come up with a better way than my solution here, I am forced to mark it as solution. If anyone comes up with a better way, I'd love to see it (and mark yours as answer!)... :)

Comment: You could also consider (depending on the details of how the async code will run) creating a `TaskCompletionSource` instead of a `Task` as the point of communication back (the routine that enqueues would create and file the `TaskCompletionSource` and return `TaskCompletionSource.Task`, then when the actual result is available, you can call `TaskCompletionSource.SetResult` to make the result available on the `Task` in the client).  This is more appropriate if you're doing e.g. a comm task where you don't need to spin up a worker thread to get your answer.